# Creating a virtual network connect for a proxy

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, proxy

Recently I found an android app named [SecureTether WiFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panjava.internet.sharing.tethering.mobile.hotspot.secure.wifi.securetether) that tethers a proxy from android phone to Windows through a local VPN connection. So the proxy is identified as a VPN connection and becomes a global connection to all Windows apps. But I don't know how SecureTether WiFi does this.

I thought there may be software or methods with which one can create a (VPN) network connection connected to a proxy server similar to what SecureTether WiFi does. So a proxy will be a (VPN) connection and all Windows apps will be connected to the proxy without any proxy settings. It globalized the proxy to the OS.

Do you know any way to convert any proxy server to a virtual (VPN) network connection in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you're confusing the concepts. There are not such possibility like conversion proxy to VPN. To reach such configuration, you need to setup VPN network, and configure it in that way, so traffic of every client will be passing through proxy server. So this is matter of VPN configuration rather than converting anything.

Maybe I misunderstood something, because I've never used such solution (there are no tethering fees in my country). I guess application you're talking about works as some kind of tunnel between wifi and mobile network, in which traffic from a connected device is treated as mobile usage.

Comment: Android provide a WIFi connection for windows. But one can use internet in windows by the proxy ip 192.168.49.1. But the app creates a VPN connection in Windows so internet is applied systemwide. No need to connect to that proxy any more. I think the proxy is transparent. All I'm looking for is how to create an internet connection in windows which uses 192.168.49.1 proxy without the help of that app. So the android proxy can be applied systemwide.